# Laravel 5.7 ApiResource GET params empty

Tags: laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.7 for my JSON API web application.

In my routes/api.php file, I created the following route :

```
Route::apiResource('my_resource', 'API\Resource')->except(['delete']);
```

I added the corresponding controller and methods (index, show,...) and everythink work perfectly. My issue is the following : I would like to add optional GET params like this :

http://a.x.y.z/my_resource?param=hello&param2=...

And for instance being able to retrieve 'hello' in my index() method. However, when I print the value of $request->input('param'), it's empty. I just don't get anything.

Yet, if I create a route like this, with an optional parameter:

```
Route::get('/my_resource/{param?}', 'API\Resource');
```

I'm able to get the parameter value in my controller method.

Here is my index method :

```
class Resource extends Controller {

public function index(Request $request)
    {
        print($request->input('param'));
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

Am I missing something ? I'm still new in Laravel maybe I missed something in the documentation.

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

$request->route("param");